# Targeting iPad Mini Retina and iPad Air 2 individually

Tags: css, media-queries

I need to target the iPad Mini Retina and iPad Air 2 individually with media queries. Currently, the same breakpoint is firing for both (using only width as a measurement). The iPad Mini Retina takes the same content and downsamples it to fit on the screen, making the text just a bit too small.

As far as I understand these should technically work to target the two devices individually, but it doesn’t:

```
@media
    (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    (min-resolution: 324dpi) {
    .standardContent {
        background-color: purple;
    }
}

@media
    (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
    (min-resolution: 263dpi) {
    .standardContent {
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

Since the two devices share the same resolution, is it possible to differentiate one from the other with a media query?

**Update**

A few people have pointed out the commas meaning “or” not “and”. I updated to use this and it still didn’t do the trick:

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-resolution: 324dpi) {
    .standardContent {
        background-color: purple;
    }
}

@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-resolution: 263dpi) {
    .standardContent {
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is the result you get always green?

Maybe the only thing that might be wrong is the order of your declarations, because the second media query includes both devices (every device with a minimum of 263dpi). you might want to switch the statements, so the 324dpi comes after the 263dpi declaration.

Comment: Switching the order just does the same thing, but showing purple.

Comment: switching the order is the right thing to do.  If that didn't work, maybe the dpi on those machines isn't what you think it is.  or...  http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-media-resolution

Comment: @andi — It didn’t work, and I’m using the actual devices. I wasn’t sure why, but apparently Safari offers only “partial” support for the `resolution` flag.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a 'max-resolution'. This will create a range for each @media. That way, the order doesn't matter at all, because no dpi value can be in both groups.

Also, i'm not sure that resolution is the best way to accomplish this. I haven't used @media in a while, and I haven't ever used them specifically for iPads, but why don't you max-device-height/width? Again, i don't use @media very often, but i figured that might be worth mentioning.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn’t solve the original issue. It should still work without `max-resolution`. It seems the problem is that there are no device properties available to CSS that differentiate the two devices. As far as CSS is concerned, both devices have a ppi of 192 and the same dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-resolution: 324dpi) {
    .standardContent {
        background-color: purple;
    }
}

@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-resolution: 263dpi) and (max-resolution:323dpi) {
    .standardContent {
        background-color: green;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn’t work for targeting iPad Air 2 and iPad Mini Retina individually.